# Are the subsets subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $X=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and $\text{Sym}(X)$ the group of bijections $f:X\rightarrow X$ with the composition of maps as the operation.

I want to check if the following subsets $U_i$ of $\text{Sym}(X)$ are subgroups of $\text{Sym}(X)$.

1. $U_1=\{f\in \text{Sym}(X)\mid f(1)\in \{1,2\}\}$

   The set $U_1$ is non-empty since $\text{Id}\in U_1$.

   Let $f,g\in U_1$. Then $f(1),g(1)\in \{1,2\}$.

   We have that $(f\circ g)(1)=f(g(1))$. When $g(1)=2$ then $(f\circ g)(1)=f(2)$  and so we don't know if $(f\circ g)(1)\in \{1,2\}$ or not?

   So $U_1$ is not a subgroup of $\text{Sym}(X)$.
2. $U_2=\{f\in \text{Sym}(X)\mid \{f(1), f(2)\}= \{1,2\}\}$

   The set $U_2$ is non-empty since $\text{id}_X\in U_2$.

   Let $f,g\in U_2$. Then $\{f(1),g(1)\}= \{1,2\}$.

   Suppose that $f(1)=1$ and $g(1)=2$ then $f(g(1))=f(2)$. Then we cannot conclude if $f\circ g(1)$ belongs to the set $\{1,2\}$, can we? And so $U_2$ is not a subgroup.

   Is this correct?
3. $U_3=\{f\in \text{Sym}(X)\mid f\circ f=\text{id}_X\}$

   The set $U_3$ is non-empty since $\text{id}_X\in U_3$.

   Let $f,g\in U_3$. Then $f\circ f=g\circ g=\text{id}_X$.

   We have that $f(f(x))=x\Rightarrow g(f(f(x))=g(x)\Rightarrow (g\circ f)(f(x))=g(x)$, or not? How could we continue?
4. $U_4=\{f\in U_3\mid f=\text{id}_X  \text{ or }   f(x)\neq x  \text{ for all } x\in X\}$

   The set $U_4$ is non-empty since $\text{id}_X\in U_4$.

   Let $f,g\in U_4$. Then $f=\text{id}_X  \text{ or }   f(x)\neq x $ and $g=\text{id}_X  \text{ or }   g(x)\neq x $.

   Then we have 4 cases for the composition:

   - If $f=g=\text{id}_X $ then $f\circ g=\text{id}_X$. So $f\circ g\in U_4$.
   - If $f=\text{id}_X $ and $g(x)\neq x $ then $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))=g(x)\neq x$. So $f\circ g\in U_4$.
   - If $g=\text{id}_X $ and $f(x)\neq x $ then $f\circ g(x)=f(g(x))=f(x)\neq x$. So $f\circ g\in U_4$.
   - If $f(x)\neq x $ and $g(x)\neq x $ then what can we say about the composition?

Comment: Number 2 is not good. Pay attention to the definition of $U_2$.

Comment: part 2: $f(g(1))= f(2)$, since $f \in U_2$, $f(2)\in \{1,2\}$.

Comment: For number $3$, notice that any transposition is in $U_3$. For instance, $(12)$ and $(23)$. Now, what happens if you compose these? You get $(132)$, which is not an involution.

Comment: For number $4$, the example above should hint at what the elements of $U_4$ look like. Each nontrivial element is the combination of two non-intersecting transpositions, and there aren't many of them: $(12)(34)$, $(13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$. You can check manually that this does form a subgroup.

Comment: Oh yes, we have that if $f(1)=1$ then $f(g(1))=f(2)\in \{1,2\}$ and if $g(1)=1$ then $f(g(1))=f(1)\in \{1,2\}$. And so $f\circ g\in U_2$, right? About the inverse: We have that if $f(1)=1$ then $1=f^{-1}(1)$ and if $f(1)=2$ then $1=f^{-1}(2)$. So $f^{-1}\in U_2$. Is everything correct and complete? @xbh

Comment: Could you explain to  me further number 4? @Fimpellizieri

Comment: Do you understand cycle notation for permutation?

Comment: Yes! Why are the elements combinations of two non-intersecting transpositions? @Fimpellizieri

Comment: Check that a permutation that is an involution cannot contain any cycle of length $3$ or greater.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! @Fimpellizieri :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying “we don't know” is not sufficient. What you need, in each case you think the subset is not a subgroup, is showing a counterexample.

For $U_1$, your idea is good. Consider $f=(23)$ and $g=(12)$. Then $f(1)=1$ and $g(1)=2$, but
$f\circ g(1)=f(g(1))=f(2)=3$. Hence $f\circ g\notin U_1$.

The subset $U_2$ *is* a subgroup

> The identity belongs to $U_2$; if $f,g\in U_2$, then $f\circ g(1)=f(g(1))\in\{1,2\}$ and $f\circ g(2)=f(g(2))\in\{1,2\}$.

For $U_3$, consider $f=(12)$ and $g=(13)$.

For $U_4$, the involutions (that is elements in $U_3$) without fixed points are $(12)(34)$, $(13)(24)$ and $(14)(23)$. Together with the identity, they form a subgroup.

Comment: At $U_2$ we have to check also the inverse, right? We have the following: If $f(1)=1$ and $f(2)=2$ then $f^{-1}(1)=1$ and $f^{-1}(2)=2$. If $f(1)=2$ and $f(2)=1$ then $f^{-1}(2)=1$ and $f^{-1}(1)=2$. So $f^{-1}\in U_2$. Is this correct?

Comment: Could you explain to me further what we have to do for $U_4$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Since the group you’re working in is finite, closure under inverses comes for free. Try $g=(1234)$.

Comment: @egreg I don't think that $g$ lies in $U_4$. $g$ should be an involution since it lies in $U_3$.

Comment: @Fimpellizieri Thanks, I didn't see $U_3$. Fixed

Comment: So, does it hold that $U_4=\{(1\ 2)(3 \ 4), (1 \ 3)(2\ 4), (1 \ 4)(2\ 3)\}$ ?

Comment: @MaryStar Plus the identity

Comment: So, to show that $U_4$ is a group we have to consider the composition of each pair and show that it is again in $U_4$ and the same for the inverse, i.e compute the inverse of each element and this must be in $U_4$, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, but that’s a well known subgroup.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you!! :-)